# No map rendering Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Community!
I was making a demo to show longitude and latitude using the Google API.
It was working fine until I copy the project to another directory. Now the map doesn't render and it shows an empty page with the google logo at the bottom.

Any Idea of what I'm doing wrong? Does this maybe have to do with the API Key?
Thank you in advance!

Here's the code:
**Main & only activity: *MainActivity***

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Fragment currentFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        currentFragment = new WelcomeFragment();
        changeFragmentTo(currentFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_welcome:
                currentFragment= new WelcomeFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_map:
                currentFragment= new MapFragment();
                break;
        }
        changeFragmentTo(currentFragment);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void changeFragmentTo(Fragment fragment){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

**2º Fragment: *MapFragment***

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,  GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener{

    private View rootView;
    private GoogleMap gMap;
    private  MapView mapView;

    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private List<Address> addresses; //object

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if (mapView !=null){
            mapView.onCreate(null);
            mapView.onResume();
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        gMap = googleMap;
        LatLng pinto = new LatLng(40.24717072159241, -3.6988735198974614);

        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pinto).title("Marker in Pinto").draggable(true));
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(pinto));
        gMap.animateCamera(zoom);

        //get information of addresses when we drag the marker
        gMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);

        geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault()); //object that gets the location

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        double latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        double longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;


        try {
            addresses=  geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,1); //limit 5
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        String city =  addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String state =  addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        String country=  addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        String postalCode=  addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Address:" + address + '\n'+
                        "City:" + city + '\n' +
                        "State:" + state + '\n'+
                        "Country:" + country + '\n'+
                        "Postal Code:" + postalCode + '\n'
                , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

**Fragment_map:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.MapFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_map_fragment" /> -->

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id ="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: this has already happened to me I don't know why with MapView displays a white screen and now I use SupportMapFragment and it works correctly

Comment: where eaxctly sorry?

Comment: instead of mapView I used SupportMapFragment but you have to change your code a bit, but I like to know why it didn't work with MapView